# I am trying to find a blank space and insert a string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a sub that will filter data and add a name to a blank range in a column. So far I have been able write the part of the code that selects and filters the data, but I would like help on how to insert a string name into a blank cell and then shoot it down the column.

I have tried an if function like `=if(cell="HEB", "HEB",0)` then show it down the column. I am looking in column D to see if the store is HEB and if it is, I would like to fill that same row in column P with "HEB"

```
Sub addHEB()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant

    fnd = ""
    rplc = "HEB"

    'Store a specfic sheet to a variable
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Perform the Find/Replace All
    sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
                      LookAt:=Range.P: P , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

I am expected this to fill down column P with "HEB" in the blank cells that correspond but it will not work. There are other blanks in the sheet so is there a more logical way to fill a blank column P with "HEB".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler to work without invoking the `Find` function. The trick is to limit your ranges because if you search for ALL of column D, that's millions of rows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillBlanksWithHEB()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheet1

    Const lastRow As Long = 10
    Dim searchArea As Range
    Dim hebArea As Range
    Set searchArea = sht.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
    Set hebArea = sht.Range("P1:P" & lastRow)

    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In searchArea
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            hebArea.Cells(cell.row, 1).value = "HEB"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```